# Python нейросеть проблемы с обучением

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Имеется код на TensorFlow (Keras) для обучения нейронки для предсказания движения курса и собственно, его предсказание. Код взят в открытом источнике и ещё не полностью доработан. Также возникают некоторые трудности, может кто нибудь подскажет, как их можно решить, вот сам код

```
import os.path
import sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from binance.client import Client

# Получение доступа к API биржи бинанс
api_key = 'Ключ'
api_secret = 'Секрет'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

# Сбор данных о криптовалютах и их изменении цен за определенный период времени
if os.path.exists("data.csv"):
    bars = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
else:
    data_file = open("data.csv", "w+")
    data_file.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame(client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "90 days ago UTC"))
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
    bars = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

bars = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "360 days ago UTC")

# Подготовка данных для обучения нейросети
data = pd.DataFrame(bars,
                    columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'close_time', 'quote_asset_volume',
                             'number_of_trades', 'taker_buy_base_asset_volume', 'taker_buy_quote_asset_volume',
                             'ignore'])
data.drop(columns=['close_time', 'quote_asset_volume', 'number_of_trades', 'taker_buy_base_asset_volume', 'taker_buy_quote_asset_volume', 'ignore'], inplace=True)
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], unit='ms')
data.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
data = data.astype(float) / 255

# Создание модели нейросети
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

MyOpt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02, momentum=0.1, nesterov=True)
# Компиляция модели
model.compile(optimizer=MyOpt,
              loss='mape')

# Обучение модели на подготовленных данных
model.fit(data.iloc[:-20], data['close'].iloc[:-20], batch_size=50, epochs=150, validation_split=0.2)

# Проверка качества работы нейросети на тестовых данных
model.evaluate(data.iloc[-20:], data['close'].iloc[-20:])

print('Сохранить текущую модель в файл? Y/N')
answer=input()
if answer == 'Y':
    model.save('model.h5')
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Проблема заключается в процессе обучения, во первых, если выдёргивать данные из файла (Если я всё правильно написал), то процесс обучения заходит в тупик и loss улетает, поэтому выдаётся nan, почему так происходит я не понимаю, пробовал разные методы и параметры оптимизации и разные функции потерь. Есть мысль что как то неправильно берутся данные из файла, так как если расскоментить bars = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE, "180 days ago UTC") То процесс обучения начинает хоть как то идти. Во вторых параметр метрики, в частности точность тут не подходит, я так понимаю, надо написать свой метод для определения точности. Активационную функцию выбрал для всех слоев relu, так как при при других опять же процесс обучения просто упадёт. Пробовал с разным кол-вом нейронов, выход один и тот же, максимум чего удалось добиться это loss = 1000 (Чего немного дофига)
Нижнюю часть, в частности проверка качества работы и использование нейронки можно пока выбросить.
Есть у кого идеи по размеру батчей, возможно мало эпох или ещё чего то не хватает. С переобучением не сталкивался, так что dropout и нормализацию батчей не использовал.

Comment: Также я понимаю, что обычную нейронку тут использовать будет неправильно. Прошу шарящих направить на путь истинный, а именно просто подсказать, какой тип нейросети выбрать, если этой окажется недостаточно, и что подправить, чтобы она хорошо обучилась